# How to auto center the table after hiding few columns in jasper report

Tags: jasper-reports

I have been hiding my columns in the table based on the columns I want to hide by passing parameters boolean value to false. It is all working fine, but the problem is when I hide the columns the whole table look likes it has moved to the left and it appears even more weird when I try hide 3 or more columns. I some how need to figure it out and bring the table to the center of the containner after hiding the columns that needs to be hidden. I not able to find any properties to make this change in jaspersoft. Please help me do this.

**MY TABLE WITHOUT HIDING**

[image]

**AFTER  HIDING THE COLUMNS**

[image]

How could I make my table center align to the container of that respective band

Comment: Some screen shot of your output?, some relevant jrxml?, what are you exporting to html?, maybe you should have used crosstabs?

Comment: Sure,  I have added some of the images to show how it is working

Comment: so how to I get the table to the center of the container when I am hidding some columns. And this report that i am generating is get a PDF.

Comment: I don't think it looks weird ; ), it looks normal... However AFIK there is no auto center property, the only solutions I can come up with is loading the result in java (JasperPrint) and move it after the fill process...